# Failed to load tensorflow BERT pre-trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, word-embedding, pre-trained-model

I tried to load a BERT pre-trained model to do NER task. But the system cannot find the pretrained model file.

I used the following code in terminal, the folder contains model.ckpt-1000000, model.ckpt-1000000.index,model.ckpt-1000000.meta files.

```
python run_ner.py \
    --do_train=true \
    --do_eval=true \
    --vocab_file=vocab.txt \
    --bert_config_file=bert_config.json \
    --init_checkpoint=model.ckpt-1000000 \
    --num_train_epochs=10.0 \
    --data_dir=NCBI-disease/ \
    --output_dir=epoch1
```

The error message is

```
2019-08-04 23:26:41.272281: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Not found: model.ckpt-1000000.data-00000-of-00001; No such file or directory

  File "/Users/anaconda/envs/BIOBERT/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/Users/anaconda/envs/BIOBERT/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: model.ckpt-1000000.data-00000-of-00001; No such file or directory
     [[node checkpoint_initializer_161 (defined at run_ner.py:422) ]]
```

Note: The original names of the model files are model.ckpt-1000000.data-00000-of-00001, model.ckpt-1000000.index and model.ckpt-1000000.meta. I also tried

```
python run_ner.py \
    --do_train=true \
    --do_eval=true \
    --vocab_file=vocab.txt \
    --bert_config_file=bert_config.json \
    --init_checkpoint=model.ckpt-1000000.data-00000-of-00001 \
    --num_train_epochs=10.0 \
    --data_dir=NCBI-disease/ \
    --output_dir=epoch1
```

Then the error would be

```
  File "/Users/anaconda/envs/BIOBERT/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 326, in NewCheckpointReader
    return CheckpointReader(compat.as_bytes(filepattern), status)
  File "/Users/SichengZhou/anaconda/envs/BIOBERT/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file ./model.ckpt-1000000.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

Comment: change `--init_checkpoint=model.ckpt-1000000.data-00000-of-00001` to `--init_checkpoint=/<path_to_checkpoint>/model.ckpt-1000000` ..... make note to remove `.data-00000-of-00001`

Answer (score 0):

The original names of the model files should be model.ckpt-1000000.data-00000-of-00001, model.ckpt-1000000.index and model.ckpt-1000000.meta.

The error you are getting is because the ckpt files and the python file you are running(run_ner.py) are in different paths.

```
python run_ner.py \
--do_train=true \
--do_eval=true \
--vocab_file=vocab.txt \
--bert_config_file=bert_config.json \
--init_checkpoint=<path to folder where ckpt files are saved>/model.ckpt-1000000 \
--num_train_epochs=10.0 \
--data_dir=NCBI-disease/ \
--output_dir=epoch1
```

Don't change `--init_checkpoint=model.ckpt-1000000` to `--init_checkpoint=model.ckpt-1000000.data-00000-of-00001` while running `run_ner.py`.

Hope this helps.